# Real Analysis: Prove a set is closed

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let R be equipped with the usual Euclidean metric. Show that the set

$S=\{(x,y) \mid 0 \leq y\leq x.\}$

is closed.

The approach i am trying is to prove the complement is open, which would imply that the set is closed. I believe the complement is the union of the set where $y < 0$ and the set where $y > x$. I understand that if I can prove that if both sets are open, then the union is open. However, i get tripped up on how to prove the sets are open,

Also as a side note: i'm new here, and any help on how to use mathematical notation such as the less than or equal sign would be appreciated

Comment: Hi: I added some TeX markup to make things render well. You can view how I did it by clicking the timestamp on my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is a good start! If you succeed in proving those two sets are open, you'll indeed be able to conclude their union is open and that their complement is closed.

Hint: To prove a set $\mathcal{O}$ is open in the ordinary Euclidean metric, you may take an arbitrary point in $\mathcal{O}$ and show that there is an open disc around it completely within $\mathcal{O}$.

An arbitrary point in the first set is an $(x,y)$ which lies below the $x$-axis. Can you find a radius around this point that stays below the $x$-axis?

Do something similar for the other set, where the point is of the form $(x,y)$ with $y>x$.

Sketching pictures and using a little simple geometry should also be helpful.

Comment: Hi. To show that the set with y < 0 is open, would it suffice to say that a a ball centered at an arbitrary point z with a radius of d(z,0)/2 (0 is the origin. Is that the proper notation?) is completely within the set? Would it work similarly for the second set, except the distance is from an arbitrary point and the line y=x? Thank you!

Comment: Dear @johndoe : No, that is not necessarily contained in the set. Consider the point $z=(4,1)$, which is distance $\sqrt{5}$ from the origin. The ball around $z$ with radius $\sqrt{5}/2$ (which I denote by $B(z,\sqrt{5}/2)$ contains the point $(4,0.1)$, for example. The real solution to this part is actually a little simpler than what you've suggested. Draw a picture and I think you'll see it.